# Get only unique post_id when checking 2 column values in different rows of the same post_id?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, case-statement

I have the following MySQL Command:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'webinar_date' AND pm.meta_value = '20190521' THEN pm.post_id
       ELSE NULL
       END AS pm_post_id
FROM wp_postmeta AS pm
WHERE pm.meta_key = 'start_time' AND CAST(pm.meta_value AS TIME) <= '21:05:44'
ORDER BY NULL;
```

I'm trying to get unique post_id values where `webinar_date` is 20190521 and time is less than or equal to 21:05:44.

According to this image of the data in the wp_postmeta table, it should return rows, but I am getting all NULL values instead.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here with this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effectively your query has an `AND` condition in it on `pm.meta_key`, wanting it to be both `'webinar_date'` and `'start_time'` at the same time to generate any rows with data. That cannot be true so all your rows contain `NULL` for `pm_post_id`. You can work around that in a number of ways e.g. with a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT pm.post_id
FROM wp_postmeta pm
JOIN wp_postmeta pm2 ON pm2.post_id = pm.post_id AND pm2.meta_key = 'webinar_date' AND pm2.meta_value = '20190521'
WHERE pm.meta_key = 'start_time' AND CAST(pm.meta_value AS TIME) <= '21:05:44'
```

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling it was something this simple.  Originally thought it could be done with 1 query and no joins.

Comment: @SolomonClosson you could do it with a single query using an `EXISTS` subquery e.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6f0bbdac66f5f2e3daf8b885938e9397 but for any decent size table I would expect the `JOIN` to be more efficient